# How do I get the currently logged-in user?

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I have a site running on Drupal 8 with a login module. I want to get the user ID for the currently logged-in user to later execute a database query.

This is the code I am using.

```php
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$uid = $user->get('uid')->value;
echo $uid;
```

In the controller of a custom module, this code works only between all using and the class controller uses the following code.

```php
namespace Drupal\CoopMatha_adh_apport\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\CoopMatha_adh_apport\Repository;
use Drupal\matha_tools\Controller\ListeController;
use Drupal\matha_tools\Controller;

$userCurrent = \Drupal::currentUser();
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($userCurrent->id());
$uid= $user->get('uid')->value;
echo $uid;  

class RapportsController extends ControllerBase {    

  // I want the user ID here.
  public function filtrer($firstLetter='', $nbr_ligne='') {
    // …
  }

}
```

How do I get the currently logged-in user ID in the controller class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I get the currently logged-in user ID in the controller class?

Controllers have a [`currentUser`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21ControllerBase.php/function/ControllerBase%3A%3AcurrentUser/8.4.x) method:

```
public function filtrer($firstLetter='', $nbr_ligne='') {
  $current_user_id = $this->currentUser()->id();
}
```